# Round n round, we go

Tags: knowledge, visual

Try to figure out the answer to this puzzle.

Here's a little info:

- Connect
- In order

[image]

Comment: Is this an puzzle found elsewhere? If so, please write the attribution. If not, please specify that it is your own puzzle.

Comment: It's my own. Why?

Comment: @Stevo While your enthusiasm is to be applauded, that's not *quite* how the attribution policy works on Puzzling. I would suggest only requesting attribution if the puzzle bears the hallmarks of having come from elsewhere. Once you become familiar with Prim3numbah's back catalogue you'll notice that their puzzles are usually their own enigmatic creations - an attribution drive is probably better spent on puzzles which contain phrases like "Can somebody explain...?" or which look like questions from tests or publications :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The secret to this puzzle lies in:

> The **12 signs of [the Zodiac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_sign)**.

First, recall that:

> the usual calendar sequence for the signs of the Zodiac is:
>
>  Capricorn - Aquarius - Pisces - Aries - Taurus - Gemini - Cancer - Leo - Virgo - Libra - Scorpio - Sagittarius
>
>  with this sequence starting again each year. (i.e. 'Round n round, we go', as per the title!)

Does this look familiar? It should do, because:

> the letter pairs in the puzzle correspond to **pairs of consecutive signs**, represented by their initials. In fact, because calendar months and Zodiac months are slightly out of step with each other, this actually corresponds to the **initials of the two signs in any calendar month**.
>
>  i.e.
>  January = Capricorn + Aquarius = **CA**
>  February = Aquarius + Pisces = **AP**
>  March = Pisces + Aries = **PA**
>  April = Aries + Taurus = **AT**
>  May = Taurus + Gemini = **TG**
>  June = Gemini + Cancer = **GC**
>  July = Cancer + Leo = **CL**
>  August = Leo + Virgo = **LV**
>  September = Virgo + Libra = **VL**
>  October = Libra + Scorpio = **LS**
>  November = Scorpio + Sagittarius = **SS**
>  December = Sagittarius + Capricorn = **SC**

Finally, returning to the image in the puzzle, we can now derive the final thematic one-word answer to the puzzle by...

> ...tracing this sequence of letter pairs, using the green-bordered squares as break points:
>
>  [image: SIGN spelled out by the boxes in order]
>
>  In other words, we spell out the thematic word **SIGN**!

Comment: Well done, all good 

Comment: How do you know not to connect the AP in the middle to the PA on the middle left, aside from just looking at the scribbles and guessing at a pattern?

Comment: @BillK Start at the green CA (January, emphasised), connect to *closest* unused next sequential letter pair, break at each green. It then falls out as above :)